# How to use gulp-clean-css to write a new -min.css file instead of the default of overwriting the existing css source file?

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, minify, gulp-clean-css

How to use gulp-clean-css to write a new -min.css file instead of the default of overwriting the existing CSS source file?

Currently, I have this line which minifies the file. However, it overwrites the original with the minified version. I would like it to create a new file with the -min.css extension at the end of the original file basename.

```
src(filePath).pipe(minifyCSS()).pipe(dest('./css/'));
```

I know there is a gulp-copy in the npm repo I could use. I would like to know if there are any other ways to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible without installing *any* additional `npm` packages, though considering the nature of NodeJS, I don't think it would be considered unreasonable to require one.

One possible way to achieve this (without `gulp-copy`) would be with [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) and the `rename` command:

```
gulp.src(config.css)

    // Output the file before cleaning
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css))

    // Clean the file
    .pipe(cleanCss())

    // Rename with a .min suffix (e.g. app.css -> app.min.css)
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))

    // Output the minified CSS file
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css));
```

This will produce two files - the unminified original `.css` file and the minified `.min.css` file.